# Can I deploy a multiclass java jar in aws lambda OR it should be always a single class file recommended in lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an existing spring boot, not a webservice but a Kafka client app. But the issue is we have been structured with typical Processor->Service->DAO layer. The jar is above 50 MB so anyway its not a candidate for aws lambda. I got some doubts, can I deploy the full jar OR should I use the step functions?. All tutorials are a single class function. Do anyone have tried out this(multiclass jar)? Also now lambda have introduced dockers. Thats adding a more confusion, can I deploy a docker, but looks like its the same under the hood.

My pick is ECS/EKS with Fargate. Basically am planning to get rid of the docker image as well. But looks like there is no way available in lambda to host my existing app other than refactoring it as step function. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy the full fat jar with the usual multi-class hierarchy, but it is not recommended due to the [Cold Start issue](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/) unless you use "Provisioned concurrency".

Here are my tips for you:

1. Keep the multi-class hierarchy, which anyways doesn't have much impact on the Jar size. This will keep your code testable. Try to remove the Spring if it is possible and create your own small dependency injection framework or use other small frameworks for that purpose.
2. Review all your dependencies, remove jars that are not needed. Our usual code is always very small, the dependent jar makes our deployable huge.